# Why app information is not updated when requesting to app store?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, axios

I have an app which has force update feature, but this feature based on the app store information. I'm using this endpoint `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1418714514`.

I'm using react-native. I tried using axios, the app info is not updated but when I downloaded it the info is correct, why does this happen?

```
axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: Constant.APP_INFORMATION_IN_APPSTORE
}).then(({ data: { results } }) => {
    const data = results && results[0]

    console.log(data)
})
```

I'm expecting latest version but the information from app store is not updated, I received previous app information

Comment: It seems like `cache` issue. Could axios `GET` request be with `no-cache` header configuration ?

Comment: @AechoLiu I can add it to `headers`, currently I have the latest version, there's a delay in getting updated information

Comment: I remember when an app published, it needs some time to spread the updated information. But I can't find the post which I saw before.